# TSQL- Export results to Excel returns single-threaded apartment mode error

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, export-to-excel

I want to export the results from a sproc to Excel.  Thus, between the exec and SELECT statements I insert the following:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Temp\testing.xls;', 
'
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM [Sheet1$]
')
```

Which returns the following error:

OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

As a basic test, I should be able to run the following query, which returns the same error:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\temp\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT Name, Date FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT [Name], GETDATE() FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
GO
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and am not using SSRS.  Any hints on how to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit SQL Server?  You can't do this with 64-bit SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered already in the comments by Barry, just following up and posting answer with supporting [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/4887d91f-6ac7-40c0-9fc8-5cdd0634e603).